# Confused with return statements

Tags: python-3.x

```
def array123(nums):
  for i in range(0,len(nums)):
    if nums[i:i+3]==[1,2,3]:
      return True
  return False
```

This is a code to check the presence of list [1,2,3] in the entered list .
Now if the list contains [1,2,3] , then True will be returned . Now my question is when the loops gets over wont the statement return False overwrite the True value returned when the list matches . Or when the list matches the value True is automatically returned without going further to the end of the function

Comment: If you want to check if a sub-list is inside a list just use `[1,2,3] in nums` which will return `True` if it is and `False` if not. You don't have to iterate manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745654/does-return-stop-a-python-script, it seems like you're asking "Does a function stop at the first return it encounters?" to which the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your second guessing is right. When passing through a "return" instruction, it will leave the function so any other lines under this one won't be executed.